# Fractions in Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

Why does the following code return 0?

```
@echo off
set a=100
set /a a=%a%*(50/%a%)

echo %a%
pause
```

I assume it's because batch at some point evaluates (50/100) as 0.5 and rounds it down to zero because it can't retain decimals before evaluating %a%*. Am I wrong, and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is floating point math with integer values. These will always be coerced into integer values. This question is asking about the same thing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-dos-batch
Essentially, you can't do floating point operations in a batch script. You will need to use some other language/technology in order to achieve your intended result.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why does the following code return 0?

Batch files do not support floating point math. To get around this limitation you have to use other scripting languages.

Powershell and VBS are possibilities:

- [Batch Script - Floating Point Math](http://www.computing.net/howtos/show/batch-script-floating-point-math/753.html)
- [SET Command - Floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951196/set-command-floating-point-numbers)

---

#### Math in NT batch files

**Limitations**

> There is a severe limitation in batch math: it can only handle 32-bit
>   integers.
>
> ...
>
> There are no real workarounds that allow floating point math, except
>   using other scripting languages. The only exception may be if you have
>   a limited and fixed number of decimals (e.g. 2), then you can just
>   multiply everything by 100. To display a decimal delimiter in the end
>   results, concatenate the ineger divide by 100, followed by the decimal
>   delimiter, followed by the modulo divide by 100:
>
> ```
> SET Whole = Result / 100
> SET "Fraction = Result %% 100"
> SET Result=%Whole%.%Fraction%
> ```
>
> This may break on the 32-bit limit, though.
>
> In general, for floating point math I would recommend using other
>   scripting languages.

Source [Math in NT batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a command shell on Windows (rather than DOS), you can use VBScript to evaluate complex expressions including floating point math for you.

I have written a small helper library you can call to do this.

[EvalBat Library on GitHub](https://github.com/adisak/EvalBat)